# Create Lambda proxy integration inside a non-root resource in API Gateway using AWS SDK with C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a proxy integration for **Lambda** invocation from **API Gateway** for a specific route (example.com/auth/{proxy+}, example.com/user/{proxy+}, etc..).

I am creating a script for automated infrastructure initialization and deployment (without using CloudFormation, Terraform, etc.) directly from .NET script that is planned to be available as an API.

Predefined infrastructure contains: Route53 config, created API Gateway with custom domain.
Dynamic infrastructure contains: S3 and Lambda together with API Gateway modifications and deployment.

Once the bucket for a new service is created and the built app is pushed to the bucket, new Lambda function is created, configured and published. The last thing that is left is to create a new resource (route) that will invoke underlying Lambda function and its underlying routes (e.g. example.com/auth/register).

The issue is that when I create an integration on a non-root resource, Lambda function cannot be found or the Uri is not specified as it should be (this is something I am trying to figure out).

Here is the simplified code that I wrote to accomplish this (I will exclude Lambda function and S3 bucket created and show only API gateway and Lambda resource policy updates as they are relevant here). **Important to note is that this code produces the same results as if it would be done via AWS console. Also, this code produces a working solution if the route is not specified (e.g. example.com/register)**

```
var functionArn = await Lambda.GetFunctionArn(accessKey, secretKey, region, lambdaFunction);
var pathResponse = await c.CreateResourceAsync(new CreateResourceRequest
{
    ParentId = rootId,
    PathPart = path,
    RestApiId = apiId
});
await c.PutMethodAsync(new PutMethodRequest
{
    AuthorizationType = "NONE",
    HttpMethod = "ANY",
    ResourceId = pathResponse.Id,
    RestApiId = apiId
});
var proxyResponse = await c.CreateResourceAsync(new CreateResourceRequest
{
    ParentId = pathResponse.Id,
    PathPart = "{proxy+}",
    RestApiId = apiId
});
await c.PutMethodAsync(new PutMethodRequest
{
    AuthorizationType = "NONE",
    HttpMethod = "ANY",
    ResourceId = proxyResponse.Id,
    RestApiId = apiId
});
await Lambda.AddPermissions(account, accessKey, secretKey, region, lambdaFunction, apiId, path);
await c.PutIntegrationAsync(new PutIntegrationRequest
{
    HttpMethod = "ANY",
    IntegrationHttpMethod = "POST",
    ResourceId = pathResponse.Id,
    RestApiId = apiId,
    PassthroughBehavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    Type = IntegrationType.AWS_PROXY,
    Uri = $"arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{functionArn}/invocations"
});
await c.PutIntegrationAsync(new PutIntegrationRequest
{
    HttpMethod = "ANY",
    IntegrationHttpMethod = "POST",
    ResourceId = proxyResponse.Id,
    RestApiId = apiId,
    PassthroughBehavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    Type = IntegrationType.AWS_PROXY,
    Uri = $"arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{functionArn}/invocations"
});
var deployment = await c.CreateDeploymentAsync(new CreateDeploymentRequest
{
    Description = $"API deployment to {environment}",
    RestApiId = apiId,
    StageName = environment
});
            
return deployment.Id;
```

where `Lambda.AddPermissions` is as follows:

```
var basePermission = await c.AddPermissionAsync(new AddPermissionRequest
{
    Action = "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    FunctionName = name,
    Principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    SourceArn = $"arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{account}:{apiId}/*/*/{path}/*",
    StatementId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
});
var proxyPermission = await c.AddPermissionAsync(new AddPermissionRequest
{
    Action = "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    FunctionName = name,
    Principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    SourceArn = $"arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{account}:{apiId}/*/*/{path}",
    StatementId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
});
                
return new List<string>
{
    basePermission.Statement,
    proxyPermission.Statement
};
```

Is there an issue with SourceArn specifications? I first created them through the AWS console (they are automatically created when the integration is created for Lambda) and they are the same.

Again, this all works when there is no path (non-root resource).

Comment: Did you consider to use AWS CDK vs SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-csharp.html?

Comment: Sure, but I want to be in full control of how I want to initialize, update and destroy my infra. CDK is a CloudFormation approach which has its benefits when you don't care how it's done. Also, CDK uses SDK or at least the underlying AWS API, so there's gotta be the way to do this

Comment: CDK converts your IaaC into Cloud Formation. You still in full control of how to define the infra. CDK solves the problem you are trying to solve. So you focus on 'what you do' vs 'how you do it'.

Comment: Let's say SDK is the preferred way for now and if any time in the future that changes, we will probably go with Terraform. But for now, I have this issue that I need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This would actually need debugging, since you are doing everything by yourself. Therefore it's difficult to debug from the information alone.

What can be checked is, if the API Gateway -> Stages ->  -> Deployment History is current. Check if there is a new deployment and if its active. You can also check the current active configuration on this page if it matches the expected one.

Note that the API Gateway configuration is split in two parts: Resources and Stages. Resources is pre-deployment and Stages is the actual currently deployed configuration. These two can differ.

Comment: Unfortunately, all these things are checked before I asked the question so I am pretty sure the stage is deployed with these modifications (resource creations). Anyways, I changed the logic at least for now and decided to create an API Gateway for each microservice collection and then have corresponding custom domains with API mappings in place (e.g. auth.example.com/, user.example.com/, etc..). This may be an even better solution as each service is now isolated on the infrastructure layer as well (no possible disruptions for other services when doing API deployments for a specific service).

Comment: If it is deployed and the permissions are correct this might be a case for the AWS support.